# Instead of Insert, Insert Value from (inserted)

Tags: sql-server, triggers

So I have a trigger on instead of insert. It runs a check, if that is okay I want a query to insert values into a table. The values needs to come from inserted though.

```
create trigger thisTrigger
on 
instead of insert
if (a check)
insert into myTable values (pnr = (select pnr from inserted))
else
```

Obviously this MSSQL code is faulty. The question is, how do I write that insert query to allow me to get the values from inserted?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: and `Instead Of` trigger is an unusually heavy hammer to use for this purpose.  The normal practice for a case like this would be to use an `After` trigger to validate the changes, and if they are not valid, the raise an exception to force the changes to rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use insert...select like this:

```
create trigger thisTrigger
on 
instead of insert
if (a check)
insert into myTable select pnr from inserted
else
-- the rest of your code
```

Comment: Yes, it does however prevent you from doing this until a few minutes has passed since the creation of the question =)